# Class 'property' does not define '__getitem__', so the '[]' operator can't be used on its instances

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am using the iloc function on a pandas dataframe named 'df'. This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

class test:
    df = pd.DataFrame
    def __init__(self):
       self.df = pd.dataframe()

    def read_csv(self):
       self.df = pd.read_csv(filename.csv)

    def operation(self, num):
       output_details = self.df.iloc[num]
       return output_deatils
```

However, I am getting this warning by my IDE:

> Class 'property' does not define '**getitem**', so the '[]' operator can't be used on its instances

I don't know what is going wrong. I am using iloc to get all the values of the 'num' row in the Pandas data frame. I think that output_details isn't actually a list with comma-separated-values, rather a pandas data type. How can I do this (or convert it to a list)?

Comment: Your example code cannot produce such a result. In particular,  both `df = pd.dataFrame` and `self.df = pd.dataframe()`  would produce `AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'dataFrame'` (ditto for `dataframe`). Please make sure the example code is representative of your problem.

Comment: @Amadan I made a mistake in the typing and had forgotten a few elements. Could you please go over it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's still not [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MCVE). In the future, please make sure you can execute your sample, then copy-paste it into the question; it avoids these kinds of problems. But if I had to guess...

`df = pd.DataFrame` does not put an instance of a DataFrame into `df`, but a `DataFrame` *class*. The class has `iloc` property, which is the way the *instance* manages to do `df.iloc[...]`; but the property object that is in the class cannot be used that way.

Here is the MCVE of your problem:

```
df = pd.DataFrame
df.iloc[0]
```

Here is a correct usage of `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0]])
df.iloc[0]
```

Obviously, this would also fix it:

```
self.df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv")
df.iloc[0]
```